# detect changes in database without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery

I create a chat webpage.
by ajax I send data to database but for showing new data to both user in chat I have to detect last changes in database.
for this problem (detect last changes without reloading page) I create a loop for each 5 sec to connect to the data base and if there was a change, return that.
but i think its not functional.
any body knows what is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: JavaScript's WebSocket API would make sense for this kind of thing. This way you're not polling the server constantly and the server can contact you.

Comment: Keep in mind if you do go the WebSocket API route, you'd need to set up an endpoint which can serve your application in a bi-directional manner. If you're on AWS, you can use AWS's API Gateway then point it at an AWS Lambda function. And in this manner you can create such an endpoint which can listen for new changes etc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-chat-app.html#websocket-api-chat-app-create-api This tutorial might also be helpful: https://medium.com/@cn007b/super-simple-php-websocket-example-ea2cd5893575